# scope into variable - Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a text box that passes the user input into a $scope. I need to pass this further along into a firebase query, but im having trouble getting the variable to register the input stored in $scope.  Code:

```
  $scope.array = [];

$scope.addListItem = function(quote){
$scope.array.unshift(quote);
console.log(quote)
this.customQuote = null;
};

  var prefix = 'tags/'
  var userInput = console.log($scope.array)

  var search = prefix + userInput


  firebase.database().ref('products').orderByChild(search).equalTo(true).once('value', function(products)
```

And the html:

```
<form ng-submit="addListItem(customQuote)" name="customQuoteForm">
          <div class="item item-input-inset">
            <label class="item-input-wrapper">
              <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder content" ng-model="customQuote" required> 
            </label>
            <button class="button button-small" ng-disabled="customQuoteForm.$invalid">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you have on the html?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you name the model in the html, you need to name it in the javascript.

I see you named it `ng-model="customQuote"`. So you should access it as `$scope.customQuote` in the javascript.

Also you are initializing the model as `null`. Don't do that, instead declare it like this:

```
 $scope.customQuote = "";
```

Comment: The example actually works fine as far as passing data from the form into the array, however, I cant get it back out to use in a variable.  for instance the 'console.log(quote)' returns the value from the text input.  Am I still missing something?

Comment: @MacD You don't need to have two customQuotes. The one in the `ngModel` is fine. No need to add another in the submit method.

Comment: using `null` is irrelevant

Comment: Yes it did, however, I don't think it answers my question.  I am trying to use the value in $scope.addListItem.  I need to combine it with the search variable so I can use it in the firebase query.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by simply moving the variable and firebase query inside the function..

```
      $scope.addListItem = function(quote){
      $scope.array.unshift(quote);
      console.log(quote)
      var tag = quote
      var text = 'tags/'

      var search = text + tag
      console.log(search)

      firebase.database().ref('products').orderByChild(search).equalTo(true).once('value', function(products) {};
```